# Pausing/resuming an upload request using Webdav on Android

Tags: java, android, upload, webdav

I'm planing to build a Webdav client for Android and I'm not sure what's the best library to use. Basically I would like to allow the user to pause and resume an upload request to a Webdav server. Is there any way to do that?

I' ve looked around and apparently I've got the choice between these libraries:

- Sardine
- JackRabbit
- Jakarta slide

Sardine looks like the most stable solution for now. I've seen nothing about pausing and resuming a request though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the original author of Sardine. I created it because Slide and Jackrabbit were too difficult to use and not well supported. The intention of Sardine was always to be run on servers, not mobile devices. Also, the design has always been around making a request and getting a response. Nothing about pausing. I have also heard that there may be issues getting it working on Android (dependencies).

That said, I hate to say it, but I think you are pretty much on your own. If you'd like to join the Sardine project to contribute patches to it to make it compatible with Android and support features like pausing, I'd love to have you (assuming you write good code. hehe).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll let you know if I build anything for Android based on Sardine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember sardine is not fully compatible with android (some missing dependencies)
About your question, i don't think is pause/resume is a part of parsing lib (which sardine i basically is). This behavior is related more with HttpClient.
However i think this is even too low abstraction level for it.
The best solution would be to implement such mechanism by hand. It's not pretty, and is connected with AIO sockets